# A computer vision algorithm to predict images from 2 images taken at different angles

Tags: image, opencv, computer-vision, interpolation

Let's say there are 2 images for a same cube. One is taken from 0 degree, and the other from 45 degree. Is there a computer vision algorithm to predict the images taken at 5, 10, 15, 25, etc, degree?

Further more, in the real world with much more complicated structures, will that algorithm work well?

I did search hard online, and failed to find answers.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like an algorithms called "loop closure" using "bag-of-words" is relevant, but I am not sure.